(India) What can be done after claiming lapsed ITC mistakingly?
What to do if you claimed a lapsed ITC (not knowing it's lapsed) one month after the deadline,  4 years back, only to be notified now (4 years later) by the government that, that ITC claimed was already lapsed and now you have to pay 3X times the original sum of ITC to the government?
How can one deal with the authorities to avoid paying the huge sum or maybe reduce it a little bit? Also isn't the government at some fault here by not taking any action 'then' or within some acceptable time range, during which the demand from government would have been payable? Does the businessman have any say in this matter?

What does your (or your business's) Chartered Accountant (CA, same as CPA for American readers)  say about the matter?

He says that during that time since GST was newly introduced he didn't know that claiming ITC late would result in fine from the gov. though that was very unexpected of him given his experience. Now, he doesn't seem to have any way to tackle this situation and also i can't force upon him any responsibility to pay the money since he is very close to family, I alone have to manage the sum.
